# Can we add automatic Pre and Post deployment approvals for YAML releases?

Tags: azure, yaml, devops

We have a requirement of adding pre and post deployment approvals automatically for YAML release pipelines in Azure DevOps. I can see Approvals and checks tab under Environments . But its like manually assigning users. We want to approve automatically without manual intervention How can we achieve this in Azure DevOps?

Answer (score 0):

> Can we add automatic Pre and Post deployment approvals for YAML releases?

`Azure DevOps` allows manual approvals for `YAML` release pipelines. However, automatic pre and post deployment approvals are not yet supported in `YAML` pipelines. Currently, manual approval checks are only supported on environments in classic pipelines. You can add `manual approvals` at the start or end of each stage in the pipeline.

You can define the approval in environment by navigating to **Pipelines > Environment > select your environment > Approvals and checks**. Then you can add the approvals in the environment.

[image]

To use pre-deployment approvals on release pipelines, you need to get approval from a user.

[image]

**References**: -  [Add stages, dependencies, & conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/stages?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#specify-approvals%29)
[Release gates and approvals overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/approvals/?view=azure-devops&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops%29&tabs=yaml)